# Django REST Framework got Server Error 500

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I followed the turial at [django-rest-framework quickstart](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/)

I have two URLs namely `/users/` and `/groups/`

The `group` works perfectly: 
[image] 
but the `user` url gets a error like this: 
[image]

> server error 500

I set `DEBUG` to `False` then add some host to `ALLOWED_HOST` in settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
    'localhost'
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

my `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from django_rest.django_rest_app import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

this is my `serializers.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['url','username','email','group']
class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Group
    fields = ['url','name']
```

and this is my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions
from django_rest.django_rest_app.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  """
  API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
  """
  queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
  serializer_class = UserSerializer
  permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  """
  API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
  """
  queryset = Group.objects.all()
  serializer_class = GroupSerializer
  permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

## UPDATE

when I set `DEBUG` to `True` again, I got this:

> Field name `group` is not valid for model `User`

I'm still a beginner, I hope you can help

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the full traceback that you get in your logs to your question

Comment: The Django `User` model does not have a field named `group`, this could be your issue?

Comment: in the log when I ```runserver``` all normal web displays appear as usual, when I write ```http: //127.0.0.1:8000/users/``` on URL, then in my log show: ```[22 / Apr / 2020 12:01:32] GET / users / HTTP / 1.1 500 145```. @IainShelvington

Comment: ya previously I got this error ```The Django User model does not have a field named group``` but now it's solved..

Comment: Is `DEBUG=True`? You should be getting a debug error page when using runserver

Comment: @IainShelvington sorry I made a typo above, my point is I set DEBUG to False. I have edited my question

Comment: @IainShelvington should I set DEBUG to True so I can see what's happening?

Comment: Yes, you will most likely get an error page letting you know where the problem is

Comment: @IainShelvington I already set DEBUG to True, and I get an error like you said. I have edited my question above

Comment: @IainShelvington if you know what I should do, I hope you might answer below

Comment: There is no field "group" on `User`, do you want to return a list of groups in the `UserSerializer`?

Comment: @IainShelvington ya I change to groups and it works, thank you for helping me

Comment: @IainShelvington Oo ya, do you know how I can GET the data from that URLs use Postman?what should I do for Authentication?

Comment: when I get in Postman just display this: ```{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212230/discussion-between-muhammad-adam-c-and-iain-shelvington).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made mistake in `UserSerializer` class

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['url','username','email','group']
```

Please change as follows

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['url','username','email','groups']
```

there is no field named `'group'` in `User` model. Instead it is `'groups'`.